# Why are these divs not aligned and space between?

Tags: css, alignment, html

Why isnt everything aligned? No yellow should be visible and no orange should be visible except for the right side and bottom left where theres space for another image.

Basically my images are pretty much aligned to the center (i have other pics not in this example which is easier to see). However in this case when i have 150px height image the 150 width seems start lower. Also why are there spaces in between

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/2jag1w7.jpg]

[image]
 [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>ldfk;sd</title>
<style type="text/css">



div.ImgGallery
{
    max-width: 630px;
    background: orange;
}

.ImgGallery div
{
    display: inline;
}
/* http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html */
.ImgGallery div div
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background: gray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.ImgGallery div{
background: yellow;
vertical-align: middle;


}
//.ImgGallery div div :nth-child(2n+1) { background: red; }
.ImgGallery * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ImgGallery a
{
    display: block;
}
.ImgGallery a *
{
    border-style: none;
}


</style>
</head>
<div class="smallGallery">
<div class="ImgGallery">

<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="b.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="b.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>
<div><div><a href="http://google.com"><img src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg"></a></div></div>

</div></div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Przykładowy dokument</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        a img {
            border: none;
        }

        #gallery {
            width: 650px;

            background: orange;
        }

        #gallery li {
            display: inline-block;

            background: yellow;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #gallery img {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="gallery">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14jyv88.jpg" /></a></li
        ><li><a href="#"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/25506e1.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the explanation:

1. Gallery is a kind of list so it should be presented in code as a list.
2. These blank spaces between images where caused by the fact that images were treated as inline elements. And you should know that one or more white char (space, enter, tab and so on) between inline elements in code is presented as a single space in browser. It's the same situation as when writing a text (which is inline).
3. Vertical alignment can be obtained using `vertical-align` property.

Comment: I couldnt get vertical-align  working in the li. But i modified the code and went backwards and got it lining up correctly. Currently theres no li (it kept a black outline and i couldnt remove it even after border: none) and use divs. It looks nice now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes, Hopefully this is what your are looking at, if you want no yellow color to be shown use `float` property of CSS.

```
.ImgGallery div
{
   display: inline-block;
}

.ImgGallery div div
{

/*display: table-cell;
 */
text-align: center;
background: gray;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;

}
```

A different issue is that your code seems to be failing standards. Try this link http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: This is a quick test. My real html is valid and i dont fix html on throwaways.